# knowing when navcontroller.popbackstack is called in jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, navigation, boolean, state, android-jetpack-compose

How can I know when navcontroller.popbackstack is called in jetpack compose?
I need a state or boolean value to understand if navcontroller.popbackstack is called to do something.

Comment: Does the [`BackHandler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/compose/package-summary#BackHandler(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function0)) work for what you are trying to do?

Comment: Did you ever figure that out?